# Unable to create a bootable Windows 10 installation on an external SSD?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, installation, operating-systems

I would like to create a portable copy of Windows 10 using an .iso of the educational version.

I work almost totally in Linux so after giving up trying to achieve this there I created a Win10 VM.

[image]

I've tried these tools:

[WinToUSB](https://easyuefi.com/wintousb/), [AOMEI Partition Assistant](https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-partition-assistant.html), and [GImageX](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/gimagex/) which all end up freezing during operations.

I'm using a brand new 275GB Crucial SSD but interestingly **Ubuntu reports a bad sector**:

[image]

Trying to run [SMART Data & Self-Tests](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html) on the drive produces this error:

```
sk_disk_smart_self_test: Operation not supported (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

When GImageX stopped progressing (at 95%...) the SSD drive seemed to have totally locked up:

[image]

The other software will also get to a point and then stop progressing. This will make the VM fairly unstable as I try to stop the processes and eject the USB drive. Normally everything ends up having to be killed and the SSD reformatted.

So where am I going wrong? Could there be an issue with the SSD even though it was brand new? I'm going to be upgrading from USB 2.0 to 3.0 but could the slow speed really be the sole problem?

Is there a better method to achieve this?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Comment: [Windows To Go: feature overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview) - "Windows To Go is a feature in Windows 10 Enterprise and Windows 10 Education that enables the creation of a Windows To Go workspace that can be booted from a USB-connected external drive on PCs."

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, Does this not require an official drive?

Comment: "Using a USB drive that has not been certified is not supported" - doesn't mean it won't work ;)

Comment: I'm getting "You can only create a Windows To Go workspace with a Windows 10 Enterprise Image"

Comment: [How to Use Windows to Go in Windows 10](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/windows-to-go-in-windows-10,2-1089.html) - "You'll need a Windows 10 Enterprise or **Education** edition physical DVD or ISO image file in order to create your Windows to Go Workspace. "

Comment: Yeah, I know it says that but it doesn't seem to be the case. I have Windows 10 Education .iso but it doesn't work. It's the same as what is being discussed [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/0f9de087-d2ee-4a0a-88c8-c795803b41ff/windows-10-education-to-go?forum=win10itprogeneral), the screenshots show the problem, just like what it does for me.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately I can't fix Microsoft bugs or incorrect documentation :/

Comment: use Rufus to create a Win10ToGo with any edition you want. if you get errors, format the drive before starting rufus.